# Run JavaScript/Jquery script online when something changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a $.post() script only when something changes on the page. If the same thing happens, then the script should run only once. If something changes, then the script should run once - not repeatedly. This script is placed in a setInterval function which runs every 5 seconds.

this is an example of what I have so far.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var status = "";
    $(selector).each(function(key,val){
        if($(val)[0].className == "A")
        {
            status = "online";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "offline";
        }

            $.post("url",{status:status});
    });
},5000);
```

In this case, the **$.post** script will run every 5 seconds. even **if status == "offline"** for 20 times in a row. even **if status == "online"** for 20 times in a row.

Any ideas on how I can run the **$.post()** script only once instead of 20? I was thinking about some **if/else** statements.. but I've got lost in details...

Comment: did you try to make an array (that will have status and some other data ) and then pass to server that will be in one call

Comment: Can you be more specific about "only when something changes"? Does it have to do an Ajax call once every five seconds anyway?

Comment: Why not compare the new value and old value and call `$.post` if it's different?

Comment: yes @Joseph.. that's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to compare two values and then see if they are different. But they could be different for 20 in a row. and I don't want the $.post to run 20 times with the same value.

Comment: You might want to clarify your post. Nowhere in the post mentions "different for 20 in a row".

Comment: 20  times in a rows was just an example - meaning that more than once. It could be 2. it could be 20. or 100

Answer (score 0):

If I get you're question correctly, you only have to remember the value before and check if the one now is different:

```
    var oldStates = {};
    setInterval(function(){
        var status = "";
        var differences = {};
        $(selector).each(function(key,val){
            if($(val)[0].className == "A")
            {
                status = "online";
            }
            else
            {
                status = "offline";
            }
            if(oldStates[key] != status){
              differences[key] = status;
            }
            oldStates[key] = status;

        });

        if(differences.length){
          $.post("url",{differences:differences});
        }
    },5000);
```

Explanation:

You save all your `oldStates`, so you know for each user if he has been offline or online the last time you checked all the states. If his `state` has changed, you save him in the `differences` array. If at least one user has changed his `state` (`if(differences.length){`), you send the data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
var status = '';
$(selector).each(function(key, value){
    if( /*... your condition ..*/ ) {
        status = 'update';
    } // no else
});

if( status == 'update' ){
    $.post('url', {status: status});
}
```

Or if you want to send every state:

```
var statuses = new Array();
$(selector).each(function(key, val){
    statuses[key] = ...
});
$.post('url', {status: statuses});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK .. so I've managed to get it running.. but using a different technique..

this is the code..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var counter = 0;
            var status = "";
            //initialize the current state
            //initialize the previous state
            var currentState = "off",
             previousState = "on";

            setInterval(function(){
                //console log the counter to see when something is happening
                console.log(counter++);

                //check the current state/class of the selector
                //if it's set to HIGH, then the currentState is on
                if($("div[data-id='selector']").hasClass("HIGH"))
                {
                    currentState = "on";
                }//else the currentState is off
                else
                {
                    currentState = "off";

                }
                //check to see what's the current state and the previous one

                if(currentState == "on" && previousState == "off")
                {
                    previousState = "on";
                    console.log("on");
                }
                else if(currentState == "off" && previousState == "on")
                {
                    previousState = "off";
                    console.log("off");
                } 
            },2000);//set up for 2 seconds just to see faster the result


            //for testing purposes -  change the class from LOW to HIGH  
            $("#on").click(function(){
                $("div[data-id='selector']").removeClass("LOW").addClass("HIGH");
            });

            //for testing purposes -  change the class from HIGH to LOW 
            $("#off").click(function(){
                $("div[data-id='selector']").removeClass("HIGH").addClass("LOW");
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="on">on</button>
    <button id="off">off</button>

    <div class="LOW" data-id="selector"></div>

</body>
```